# Website container won't align to the centre (Mobile and web)

Tags: html, css

Hoping that the community will be able to help me out here as I really am stuck. I've having 3 I issues with my website:

[Website Link](http://www.tristenwest.com)

1. For some odd reason - I can't get my columns to line up straight. The entire page seems to be more to the right than in the centre on both desktop and mobile
2. What I'm trying to do with the top image is have it take up the entire page upon loading, and then as you scroll, the image disappears. For some reason, on mobile, the image doesn't cut off and allows for the user to scroll to the right.

   1. On mobile, I can't get the top image to show properly. It stretches vertically, and users have to scroll all the way past the photo to get to my content... I want the main image to resize like it does on a desktop browser and only take up the screen real estate when the page loads

Any advice here would be helpful...

Comment: Please post a fiddle or code + css

Comment: where is the 3rd issue?

Comment: Sorry - only meant two issues. Just need help solving this background image mystery now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your projects sections - if that is where your issue is has padding on a UL tag - which is causing it to look misaligned.

You could do this to fix that section:

```
ul.skillssection {
  padding-left: 0;
}
```

It'll be more helpful for the community if you made points or set up a jsfiddle.

Update - answer for number 2.

I can't seem to replicate it but I've noticed you've got:

```
img.bg {
  min-height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 780px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

I would change it to:

```
img.bg {
  min-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

So the max-width is always 100% and it should follow the width of the parent.

Comment: Also - your contact area - you need to add CSS for the input/textarea elements: `box-sizing: border-box;` and it'll align those properly.

Comment: How should a JSFiddle be more helpful than the link to the page!? And if you follow the (given) link to the site, you'll see the described problem(s). Additionally I get a horizontal scrollbar in Firefox (29 Win 7) on my desktop (Full HD).

Comment: Appreciate this. Fixed issue #1.

Comment: @Netsurfer - that's true - I was in a rush so was hoping for a page with isolated incidents.

Comment: Hoping that someone can assist with my third issue.